# QGraphicsScene on a QMainWindow

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, qgraphicsscene

Still new to Python so I'm trying to get a QGraphicsScene to be inside a a QMainWindow.  Right now the way I have it coded is that two windows will appear but I only want one window to appear with the QGraphicsScene "inside" the QMainWindow.  Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)

        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.item = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(300,400,100,100)
        self.scene.addItem(self.item)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        #This initializes the main window or form
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,900,700)
        self.setWindowTitle("Pre-Alignment system")

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    view = MyView()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt (and other GUI toolkits) believe in parenting. The have one window or widget within another, set its parent. Note that you should be calling show on the outer one.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.item = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(300,400,100,100)
        self.scene.addItem(self.item)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        #This initializes the main window or form
        super(Window,self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setGeometry(50,50,900,700)
        self.setWindowTitle("Pre-Alignment system")

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    view = MyView(GUI)
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Comment: only one window popped up but the graphicsscene did not show up on the MainWindow.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Oh no, it's there! The little thing in the top-left corner is your graphics scene, with scroll bars. To get elements to display nicely one within the other, I recommend you read up on sizers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your `QGraphicsScene` inside your `QMainWindow` (just like you want it to appears)

Then in the main, you only create an instance of `Window` and show it.

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        #This initializes the main window or form
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,900,700)
        self.setWindowTitle("Pre-Alignment system")
        #create the view
        self.view=MyView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ok that seemed to work. Can I ask why you used the setCentralWidget() method?

Comment: Since you were using `QMainWindow` and had only one widget to show inside, it was the easiest way. Otherwise, you have to create a layout.

Comment: can i move the graphicscene by just doing self.view.move(x,y)? or is there something more I have to do?

Comment: What do you want to do ? Do you have other things you want to put in your main window ? If so, use layouts.

Comment: well I have tons of buttons and QLE's already on my GUI form but I didn't include it in my question because that's like 700 lines of code haha.  I've been placing the buttons by using the move method rather than layouts I guess.

Comment: Could I put the scene or view inside of a layout? sorry for the spamming by the way.

Comment: @MatthewS2494 Use layouts for everything. It will make your life easier.